# Get HREF values without CLASS or ID using Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

i'm trying to get HREF value on a page but there's no CLASS or ID.

```
<div class="columns">
    <a href="http://www.website.com/page.html?id=123"></a>
</div>
```

I tried,

```
a = Mechanize.new
page = a.get("http://www.website.com/index.html")
url = page.links_with(:href => "^http://www.website.com/page.html?id=").href
puts url[0]
```

Any idea? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following.

```
a = Mechanize.new
page = a.get("http://www.website.com/index.html")
url = page.link_with(:text => "http://www.website.com/page.html?id=")
puts url
```

Updated Answer:

```
a = Mechanize.new
page = a.get("http://www.sainte-maxime.com/-locations-de-vacances-.html")
urls = page.links_with(:href => /.*?id\=/).map{|h| h.href}
puts urls
```

Comment: @Rubyx give me site url so i give proper answer.

Comment: [url](http://www.sainte-maxime.com/-locations-de-vacances-.html) `div.class="large-4 medium-6 small-12 columns" `

Comment: it works thank you! Can you explain me the `.` between `/` and `*`, is it `http://www.website.com/` ?